# SQL Server Query Removing Percentages

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace, percentage

I was wondering if there was a way to specifically look for percentages using say the replace Function in SQL?

Say for Example I have the data:

- Ollie is at work 1% of the time
- Ollie 2 is at work 2% of the time
- Ben is at work 2.1% of the time

I do not want to replace other numbers in the results only the percentages.

Is there a way to do this currently I use:

```
UPDATE DataTable SET PersonInfo = replace(PersonInfo, '%', '' );
```

But I do not know a way to select the data(numbers) relating to the percentage...

Desired Output:

- Ollie is at work of the time
- Ollie 2 is at work of the time
- Ben is at work of the time

Comment: What are you expected result for the data above? Are you looking to change `'Ollie is at work 1% of the time`' to `'Ollie is at work  of the time'` ???

Comment: That is correct Larnu, I would just like to strip the percentages out of the query results i.e. 'Ollie is at work of the time'

Comment: Not sure SQL Server is the correct choice for this, in all honesty. I have an idea though...

Comment: What's your input/idea Larnu it may be of help for tasks like this I am open to language changing/integrations :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some basic string operations:

```
SELECT *,  
      REVERSE(
      STUFF(REVERSE(PersonInfo),
        CHARINDEX('%',REVERSE(PersonInfo) ),
        CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(PersonInfo),CHARINDEX('%',REVERSE(PersonInfo))) - 
        CHARINDEX('%',REVERSE(PersonInfo) )+1,
       '')
       )
FROM DataTable
WHERE PersonInfo LIKE '%!%%' ESCAPE '!';
```

**[Dbfiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e07d162c1658ca4eeedff2b1849d1f26)**

Answer (score 1):

My answer is very similar to lad2025's:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('Ollie is at work 1% of the time'),
                ('Ollie 2 is at work 2% of the time'),
                ('Ben is at work 2.1% of the time')) V(S))
SELECT *,
       STUFF(VTE.S, CI.P - RCI.S + 2 , RCI.S,'')
FROM VTE
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX('%',VTE.S))) CI(P)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LEFT(VTE.S,CI.P))))) RCI(S);
```

I just used `CROSS APPLY` instead.

If you wanted to do this as an `UPDATE` statement, it would be:

```
UPDATE DT
SET PersonInfo = STUFF(DT.PersonInfo, CI.P - RCI.S + 2 , RCI.S,'')
FROM DataTable DT
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX('%',DT.PersonInfo))) CI(P)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LEFT(DT.PersonInfo,CI.P))))) RCI(S);
```